# multiple small programs in one code::blocks project

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am new to Code::Blocks. For my studies I am programming several small programms in C (just to try things out). 
I tried to put them all in one project, because they belong to the same topic, but that doesn't work because each of them has a main function.

Any ideas how I can put those files together somehow, but not depending on each other?

Comment: you can create your own make file

Comment: sorry, am new to C, what do you mean, and how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say that your project contains 3 c files and each c file is a separate program and it contains its own `main` function:

- program1.c
- program2.c
- program3.c

So you can write a Makefile (its name in your computer should be **"Makfile"**). It will  build the program you want separately

This is how your makefile looks:

```
all: program1 program2 program3

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

program1: program1.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

program2: program2.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

program3: program3.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f *.o program1 program2 program3
```

with the above Makefile you can build each program separetly

example

```
$ make program1
```

will build only program1

or you can buil all programs with

```
$make all
```

Comment: So where do I enter `$make program1` ? Command Line? Normally I do Build&Run with F9.

Comment: @mvuajua I'm a little confused why you accepted this as the answer as it doesn't actually answer your question about code::blocks.

Comment: @neuronet it's been five years, but I think this is what I went with at the time, and other answers came way later

Answer (score 9):

Suppose your source files are called

- prog1.c
- prog2.c
- mylib.c
- mylib.h

where prog1.c and prog2.c each contain a main() function and mylib.c (with the corresponding header file mylib.h) contains some library functions that should be linked to each program. In your Code::Blocks project you need to create multiple targets now. From the menu choose 'File/New/Build target...' and name them 'prog1' and 'prog2'. Now add all of your source files to the project (in case you haven't done so already).

Now right-click on prog1.c and select "Properties..." from the context menu. In the dialog box choose the 'Build' tab and make sure that under "Belongs to target" only "prog1" is checked. Do the same with prog2.c and the target "prog2". For "mylib.c" make sure that both "prog1" and "prog2" are checked.

Now you can easily choose in the UI which build target to build and run. Note that if you add another target, say "prog3", then you have to go to the build properties of prog1.c and prog2.c again and uncheck "prog3".

Answer (score 2):

A **C** program should contain only one main function.. Divide all your separate programs as **Functions** and put them in a single C program or you can even put it in multiple files and compile them..

You can use a `switch case` for calling different functions..

Remove the `main function` from all the programs and convert them into `functions`..

Call them where ever required.. This will help you..

Comment: I know that a C programm should only contain one main function. I dont want to put them into functions, because those small programs are independent and not belong together, so calling all of them from just one file wouldnt make sense to me.

Comment: No, that doesn't help me because I have to hand in those files later and then they have to be independent. I just want to compile & run the file which I am working on, not all files. If there is no possibility to do that, I will change back to my old editor.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me as if you are starting to build some nice utility functions.  So follow the advice offered by raghu-srikanth-reddyce and create separate functions for each little program.  However I would add that it would be better to create yourself a simple C library to keep them all in which you can link to at any time.  Most professional programmers keep such libraries.

A simple makefile will enable you to build a final binary that you can link to.

Good luck with your programming ;)

Comment: Nope, am just doing the tasks given by the prof. I just want to compile just one file, independent of the others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile in one file, you dont need a **Project File** then.
Just make a **New File**, then write all the code in a single file. Also use **Function** and **Procedure** if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite late but since I was once here with the same question, and I believe most students had/ have/ will have this same question, let me elaborate where you have been played at.

In Educational Courses and in Real World, a project is (in general) some problem you work on, find a solution, then make a report (+ documentation) on it.

In Programming IDE, a project is the problem's solution itself. Hence, while you may have multiple individual problems within one project in any Python IDE, Any standard C/C++ IDE project must have only one 'main()' to rule them all (unless you know how to create makefiles).

What the AP tried to do is to put several different problem's solutions fit within one solution's space - not a possible thing to do in Code::Blocks. Even if all the problems may share the same topic (say, Graph Theory), they are individual problem (Dijkstra vs Floyd) themselves.